# Xpath select function?

Tags: xpath

I'm using feed import module in Drupal 7 cms that accepts xpath directives to map the data for the import. Is it possible to select only part of the atomic value or explode it with xpath?
For example:

```
<book>
...
<categories>1,4,88</categories>
...
</book>
```

Is it possible to get only 1 or 4 or 88 separately with xpath statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use the [substring-before()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring-before) and [substring-after()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring-after) functions:**

- To select 1: `substring-before(/book/categories, ',')`
- To select 4: `substring-before(substring-after(/book/categories, ','), ',')`
- To select 88: `substring-after(substring-after(/book/categories, ','), ',')`

---

**With XPath 2.0 you could use the [tokenize()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) function:**

- To select 1: `tokenize(/book/categories, ',')[1]`
- To select 4: `tokenize(/book/categories, ',')[2]`
- To select 88: `tokenize(/book/categories, ',')[3]`

Answer (score 1):

**Or, using XPath 2.0, one can access the `N`th component by**:

```
tokenize(/*/categories[1], ',')[$pN]
```

where `$pN` is the desired 1-based index.